# KVM/Spice/Remote-Viewer: Need assistance troubleshooting USB redirection

Tags: usb, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Bottom line up front: I'm unable to redirect USB from my desktop to the VM. 'USB Device Selection ' is always grayed out in Remote-Viewer and in full screen it says that 'USB redirection support not compiled in'.

The details: 
The host KVM server is Ubuntu Server 14.04 and I have installed qemu-kvm (kvm -version = QEMU emulator version 2.0.0 (Debian 2.0.0+dfsg-2ubuntu1.7)), libvirt-bin, bridge-utils, ssh.

The guest is a Win7 VM which was created using virt-manager remotely from an ubuntu desktop. Some of the pertinent settings for the VM: the display is set to Spice, video is set to QXL, there is a 'Controller USB' present, there is a 'Redirected USB' present.

The desktop which I'm trying to redirect USB from is Win7 and I'm using Remote-Viewer which came from spice-space.org.

I have been reading lots of information and everything tells me that this should be working. When I connect to the VM with Remote-Viewer, the menu item for 'USB device selection' is always grayed out and if full screen it then says the 'USB redirection support not compiled in'. I'm not sure if this message is accurate or not, because I'm under the impression that Remote-Viewer has this compiled in by default. In fact, looking through the files in the installation folder, there is one the shows all the dependencies and it is in there. So I'm not sure where to go from here for troubleshooting. I have looked at lots of things in terms of configuration and nothing jumps out at me. If someone could point me in a direction to aid in troubleshooting this, it would be most appreciated!

Update #1 (11/28/2014):
I took 'audiomobster' advice and compiled qemu on the host that I'm trying to get the USB redirection to work on. Below are the commands I used to compile.

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential zlib1g-dev
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends -y build-dep qemu
wget http://wiki.qemu-project.org/download/qemu-2.1.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvf qemu-2.1.0.tar.bz2
cd qemu-2.1.0/
./configure --enable-usb-redir
make
sudo make install
```

The compilation ran without error and afterwards I was able to run `$ kvm --version` and I get the updated version that I just compiled returned. `QEMU emulator version 2.1.0, Copyright (c) 2003-2008 Fabrice Bellard`. I can run virt-manager remotely against it and I can still run the VM, but I still get the same message ('USB redirection support not compiled in') in virt-viewer (remote-viewer). I have been assuming the message is referring to qemu, but I'm now wondering if it is referring to 'remote-viewer' itself? I got the remote-viewer ('virt-viewer' on the page) from http://www.spice-space.org/download.html. Based on the docs that I have read, it sounds like the Windows binaries should work with USB redirection just as they are. Anyone out there using it successfully without changes of any kind for USB redirection? If I can rule that out, I think I can continue to focus my troubleshooting on qemu and the comms between my desktop and the host. Sort of working through process of elimination at this point. Again, appreciate any thoughts on this issue...thanx!

Answer (score 0):

Although I've got a gentoo flavor maybe this gives you a hint.
Recompiling qemu and spice-gtk with **usbredir** USE flag did the job for me. Should be a **./configure** parameter for you.